# How to scale image with with transition CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

I want my image to scale when a mouse is on it.

I try to adapt [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) example. See `img` and `img.hover`

CSS:

```
h1 {
    text-align:center;
    animation: acid 1s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: acid 1s infinite;
}

div { 
    text-align:center;
}

hr {
    width:30%;
}

img {
    width:629px;
    height:321px;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease, height 1s ease;
}

img.hover {
    width:944px;
    height:481px;
}

@keyframes acid {
    0% {color:blue}
    50% {color:red}
    100% {color:blue}
}

@-webkit-keyframes acid {
    0% {color:blue}
    50% {color:red}
    100% {color:blue}
}
```

The image, that is supposed to be scaled is defined with `<img src="http://www.jose-aguilar.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/html-colors.png" alt="Colors">`

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>0_0</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my_styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>I am page header</h1>
        <div>Below there are <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color">colors </a>:</div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://www.jose-aguilar.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/html-colors.png" alt="Colors">
        <div>
        <!--You are looking at the source of this page-->
        <hr>
        <button type="button">I am button</button>
        <div>I don't do anything</div>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" style>option 1<br>
            <input type="checkbox">option 2 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Changing pixel values to percents values in `img` and `img.hover` doesn't help. Tested in Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to use Pseudo-classes

```
img:hover
```

For more detailed information refer this 
[Pseudo-classes on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes). Much better than w3schools.

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple error in your markup...`img.hover` should be `img:hover`.

Please see the [pseudo-class specification from W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act).

Answer (score 1):

Its not

```
img.hover
{
    width:944px;
    height:481px;
}
```

its  [**:hover**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

```
img:hover
{
    width:944px;
    height:481px;
}
```

[**FIXED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fhwgq2jj/)